# Android: Photos force captured in Landscape mode

Tags: android, image, camera, photo

Hi have built on [Camera Preview](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/CameraPreview.html).

Origionally it displayed a landscape preview even in portrait mode. I changed this with some extra code. However, no matter if your landscape/portrait, it always saves images in landscape mode.

Ive also now forced it to portrait mode:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

**Basically any image I take comes out in landscape. (rotates a portrait taken image).**

How would I make it save photos in the orientated mode, or locked to portrait assumption?

Ive considered taking the photo array and rotating 90 degrees. But that would require drawing the image to a bitmap, rotating and then storing back to an array. Overkill much? Unless you can rotate an image array directly?

Comment: You need to save images only in Landscape mode right? @Doomsknight

Comment: Id rather they were only saved in portrait mode. Or for it to detect the current orientation and act accordingly

Answer (score 9):

First Check the Camera Orientation using below Snippet :

```
    private int lookupRotation() {       
       WindowManager mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
       Display mDisplay = mWindowManager.getDefaultDisplay();
       int rotation = mDisplay.getRotation();
       Log.v(LOG_TAG, "rotation: " + rotation);
       return rotation;
   }
```

then check your desired rotation using and set your orientation :

```
if (rotation == Surface.ROTATION_0) {
    int degreesRotate = 90;
}
```

Resize the Bitmap and rotate your Bitmap based on orientation using below Snippet :

```
    private Bitmap createBitmap(byte[] imageData, int maxWidth, int maxHeight,
        int rotationDegrees) throws FileNotFoundException {

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = 2;
    options.inDensity = 240;
    int imageWidth = 0;
    int imageHeight = 0;

    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0,
            imageData.length, options);

    imageWidth = image.getWidth();
    imageHeight = image.getHeight();

    if (imageWidth > maxWidth || imageHeight > maxHeight) {

        double imageAspect = (double) imageWidth / imageHeight;
        double desiredAspect = (double) maxWidth / maxHeight;
        double scaleFactor;

        if (imageAspect < desiredAspect) {
            scaleFactor = (double) maxHeight / imageHeight;
        } else {
            scaleFactor = (double) maxWidth / imageWidth;
        }

        float scaleWidth = ((float) scaleFactor) * imageWidth;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) scaleFactor) * imageHeight;

        Bitmap scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image,
                (int) scaleWidth, (int) scaleHeight, true);
        image = scaledBitmap;
    }

    if (rotationDegrees != 0) {

        int w = image.getWidth();
        int h = image.getHeight();
        mtx.postRotate(rotationDegrees);
        Bitmap rotatedBMP = Bitmap.createBitmap(image, 0, 0, w, h, mtx,
                true);
        image = rotatedBMP;
    }

    return image;
}
```

The above method will returns bitmap based on Orientation.

Comment: will this still work with orientation forced to portrait? (rotating the screen was causing everything to recreate unnecessarily - leading to lag and bad animation rotation effect). Looking at the getrotation code it seems to be checking the phones orientation rather than my app? -  Ill give it a try, looks promising

Comment: This is an idea for Handling Orientation , just customize as per your requirement if needed

Comment: This still only obtains the applications orientation. And since fixed to portait now, for speed reasons, assumes portrait orientation when taking picture. Unsure how to get the actual orientation of the phone

Comment: +1 for the great answer, which contains everything the OP needs. -1 for the OP for not even saying 'thanks'... Or accept it as right answer for that matter.